# Include SQL file to another SQL file

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, include, init

I have a specific SQL file that may be "connected" to another, more generic SQL init file.

Is it possible to somehow include reference from one SQL file to another SQL file?

I am using Oracle and the DB is populated using Spring `DataSourceInitializer` class.

Comment: i've resolve this issue by providing one more bean,that defines whether additional scripts needed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using SQL*Plus to run your script, you can use the @ (or @@) sign to include another SQL script.

See the manual for details:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12002.htm#i2696724

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12003.htm#i2696759